# Groovy list of lists to map with first list as keys

Tags: groovy, collections

How would I go in Groovy idiomatically (with collection methods?) from

`[['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`

to

`[[a: 1, b: 2, c: 3], [a: 4, b: 5, c: 6]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def x=[['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

x.tail().collect{v-> x.head().indexed().collectEntries{i,k-> [k, v[i]] } }
```

Comment: Simpler maybe: `x.tail().collect { v -> [x.head(), v].transpose().collectEntries() }`